# UNIX - Grep from a list file 2 same lines

Tags: unix, grep

What I'm trying to do is to search the corresponding from each line from a file into another file; but with EACH lines finding a corresponding line, if possible, in the other file, even if two lines from the first file are the same.

Here are the content of the different files:
Data_1.txt

```
chr12   132401672   132401673   GA  -
chr12   132401743   132401743   T   -
chr12   132401743   132401743   T   -
chr12   132402020   132402020   T   C
```

Data_2.txt

```
chr12   132401675   132401675   -   TT  intronic
chr12   132401743   132401743   T   -   intronic
chr12   132401951   132401951   C   T   splicing
```

I'm trying to "grep" the content of Data_1 to have corresponding lines in Data_2.

Here is **wanted** result:

```
chr12   132401743   132401743   T   -   intronic
chr12   132401743   132401743   T   -   intronic
```

My current code is this one:

```
grep -w -f Data_1.txt Data_2.txt
```

But the current result is:

```
chr12   132401743   132401743   T   -   intronic
```

Because there is the two same lines in Data_1.txt, grep only gives me one result (because it exists only one time in the second). But I would like to have, for each line of Data_1.txt, a corresponding result (if it does exist) in Data_2.file, even if it is the same line.

I know that I could make a loop with a:  `for a in 'more Data_1.txt'; do grep -w "$a" Data_2.txt; done`  , but the original file from this example come from is much, much bigger, and it's taking too much time to run it.

Maybe there's a way to do it with awk or another function, but I don't know how.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
while read line; do grep "$line" data2.txt; done < data1.txt;
```

Comment: This command works, indeed, but it seems to have the same problem than a "for" loop: it is quite slow. 
I made the test with the real files, which have both more than 60K lines (and a lot of extra columns), and while hasn't finished the job in 10 minutes, when the grep has finished it in 40s. (But maybe I haven't coded it well).
If it was only on one file, I could do it, but I have 220 file to analyse and I can't afford to spend so much time on that. 
But thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need `grep -f`, as explained in [this URL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127601/grep-file-from-file).

For you, this means the following:

```
grep -Ff Data_1.txt Data_2.txt
```

Comment: It doesn't give the result wanted... Considering the -v is an error of copy (given that I don't want the reverse search), grep -Ff Data_1.txt Data_2.txt gives exactly the same result than my code.

Comment: The `-v` was a typo indeed, I updated my answer, does it work now?

Comment: The code does work, but doesn't give the wanted result, as the output is only one line.

Comment: I might have switched data_1 and data_2, can you check?

Comment: `grep -Ff Data_1.txt Data_2.txt` gives the same result as my current code (one line when I need two). 

`grep -Ff Data_2.txt Data_1.txt` gives no results at all.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's not really satisfying, if someone has the same problem than me and need a solution at any cost, here's what I have done to solve it:

```
grep -w -f Data_1.txt Data_2.txt > file.txt
sort Data_1.txt | uniq -c | awk -v OFS='\t' '$1>1 {print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'> Data_temp.txt
grep -w -f Data_Temp.txt Data_2.txt >> file.txt
sort file.txt
rm Data_Temp.txt
```

(You can add lines if there's more than 2 repeats in your file, with `awk '$1>2'` or more)

I know it's really ugly to see, but it works. If someone has a better solution, it is welcome.